# How to change values in string in java?

Tags: java, string

how to change values in ​​string in java

```
 String s = "Welcome!This is CS211 Course";
```

I want to change word `"CS211"` to `"CS222"`

so s will be Permanently = `"Welcome!This is CS222 Course";`

Comment: `s = "Welcome!This is CS222 Course"`

Comment: Will the string to be replaced always be CS211 ?. Will it always be present only once?. You have given very little information.

Comment: Please read about string `immutability` in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Strings are immutable in Java. Think of them as being stored in read-only memory. (The JVM can perform all sorts of optimisation tricks if it knows that something cannot be changed).

What you *can* do it to create another string and assign that to the reference `s`:

`s = s.replace("CS211", "CS222");`

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "Welcome!This is CS211 Course";
s = s.replace("CS211", "CS222");
```

Try to use google before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s2 = s.replace("CS211", "CS222");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, String object is immutable. That means, once assigned, its content cannot be changed. So, to change the content, you need to make a different string, which could be referred bt same reference, but essentially different. Thus, possibility one is to have:

```
s = "Welcome!This is CS222 Course";
```

Other possibility is to call replaceAll for s and assign to s again (changed) as suggested by WidWing

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, I do not have enough rep points to comment...yet!

Might I suggest http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

This will help you understand the basics & get started.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that String are [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This means that cannot be modified. Of course there are methods to obtain a new String. But the old string won't be modified at all.

Example:

```
String s = "Welcome!This is CS211 Course";
String s2 = s;
s.replace("CS211", "CS222"); // Gets a new object but I do not save it at all

System.out.println(s); // This prints "Welcome!This is CS211 Course"

s=s.replace("CS211", "CS222"); // Now I replace the reference to s.
System.out.println(s);  // This prints "Welcome!This is CS222 Course"
System.out.println(s2); // This prints "Welcome!This is CS211 Course". s2 reference has not changed.
```